# Nx + Firebase: Can't run emulators

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to run the Firebase emulators in the Nx workspace.

I added firebase to the project:

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save

nx g @angular/fire:ng-add // sets up package in project (this didn't work)
ng add @angular/fire // sets up package in project (this worked)
```

I initialized firebase in the local folder:

```
firebase init
```

I tried to run the emulators:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

And I'm getting the following console output:

> PS C:\repos\todoapp> firebase emulators:start i  emulators: Starting
> emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, storage !  functions:
> The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from
> the Functions emulator will affect production: database, pubsub
>
> - functions: Using node@14 from host. i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log i  hosting: Serving hosting
>   files from: dist/todoapp
> - hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000 i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log i  functions: Watching
>   "C:\repos\todoapp\functions" for Cloud Functions... !  Error: Cannot find
>   module 'C:\repos\todoapp\functions\lib\index.js'. Please verify that the
>   package.json has a valid "main" entry
>   at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
>   at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:534:18)
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
>   at initializeRuntime (C:\Users\patri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:687:29)
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
>   at async handleMessage (C:\Users\patri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:729:20)
>   !  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
>
>   - It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.
>   - You may be able to run "npm run build" in your functions directory to resolve this.

Can't Nx work with Firebase seamlessly?

Do I have to do some additional setup to make it run seamlessly, like in standard Angular environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this one too. In your `functions` folder you need to execute `npm run build` to generate the file it's looking for.